# Filter by number of duplicates, in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am utilising a dataset that includes one column that comprises of phone numbers, and one column that includes yes or no.

```
  phone.number yes.no
1   7539339393      Y
2    111111111      N
3   1234567890      Y
4   7539339393      N
5   1222222222      Y
6   3333333333      N
7   4444444444      Y
8   5555555555      N
9   7539339393      Y
```

`dput` below:

```
structure(list(phone.number = structure(c(7L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("111111111", "1222222222", "1234567890", 
    "3333333333", "4444444444", "5555555555", "7539339393"), class = "factor"), 
        yes.no = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", 
        "Y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("phone.number", "yes.no"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

There are two things that I'd really appreciate some help with.

1. I am trying to create a subset that includes all phone numbers that have been repeated 3 or more times within the dataset. So, in the example provided, the number 7539339393 is repeated 3 times, the subset that I'd like to make would just include these observations and the corresponding yes and no values.
2. I am also trying to subset for all phone numbers that have returned yes and no. So, within the dataset provided, 7539339393 has corresponded to both yes and no, I'd like to create a subset with all of the phone numbers that return both and all of the corresponding yes and no values

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide a reproducible example. This includes copy-pasting some data (nobody is going to type in the data from your image) and what you've already tried.

Comment: Hi Heroka, I'll do that now, thanks for letting me know (still new here)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your link goes to an image. Not useful. *Provide your data*. Either upload as, say, csv, and provide a link, or (better) import into R and provide the output of `dput(mydata)`, directly in your quesiton.

Comment: I've editted the question with an update, is this more helpful?

Comment: Well done with the edit and inclusion of the data! What have you already tried yourself to fix your problem?

Comment: For 1) try `df[df$phone.number %in% names(which(table(df$phone.number) >= 3)),]`. For 2) `df[as.logical(ave(as.character(df$yes.no), df$phone.number, FUN= function(x) all(c("Y", "N") %in% x))),]`

Comment: To be honest, I'm a bit stumped. I've been googling left right and centre, but I can't seem to make sense of it. I guess my issue is that I know how to analyse something within a row, but between rows seems confusing.

Comment: Thank you Pierre, will give that a go now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`,

For 1:

```
df[df$phone.number %in% names(which(table(df$phone.number) >= 3)),]
#  phone.number yes.no
#1   7539339393      Y
#4   7539339393      N
#9   7539339393      Y
```

We subset based on phone numbers that appear 3 or more times. `table` takes a tally of all elements in the vector.

For 2:

```
df[as.logical(ave(as.character(df$yes.no), df$phone.number, FUN= function(x) all(c("Y", "N") %in% x))),]
#  phone.number yes.no
#1   7539339393      Y
#4   7539339393      N
#9   7539339393      Y
```

There are nice grouping functions in `dplyr` and `data.table`, this is one base R approach that may either highlight the strength of base R or the advantage of other packages depending on how you look at it. It is a bit verbose as a one liner. Working from the inside out, `all` is used to check if yes and no appear. The function `ave` helps to complete the operation by unique phone number.

Answer (score 1):

Possible `dplyr` approaches..

For 1.:

```
df %>% group_by(phone.number) %>% filter(n() >= 3)
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#Groups: phone.number [1]
#
#  phone.number yes.no
#        (fctr) (fctr)
#1   7539339393      Y
#2   7539339393      N
#3   7539339393      Y
```

(`n()` returns the number of rows per group in dplyr)

For 2.:

```
df %>% group_by(phone.number) %>% filter(all(c("Y", "N") %in% yes.no))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#Groups: phone.number [1]
#
#  phone.number yes.no
#        (fctr) (fctr)
#1   7539339393      Y
#2   7539339393      N
#3   7539339393      Y
```

For 1. + 2. combined:

```
df %>% group_by(phone.number) %>% filter(n() >= 3 & all(c("Y", "N") %in% yes.no))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#Groups: phone.number [1]
#
#  phone.number yes.no
#        (fctr) (fctr)
#1   7539339393      Y
#2   7539339393      N
#3   7539339393      Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a data.table solution, calling your dataset `df`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.SD[.N>2],by=phone.number]
#    phone.number yes.no
# 1:   7539339393      Y
# 2:   7539339393      N
# 3:   7539339393      Y
```

For the second part:

```
df[,.SD[length(unique(yes.no))>1], by=phone.number]
```

Note that `setDT(df)` converts `df` to a data.table, so you don't have to call it again in the second part.

This approach is likely to be faster than any other method, although unless your data set is extremely large you might not notice the difference.

Comment: The second part might not work as expected if there could be `NA` entries in the column (not clear from the example but just in case).